# OAUth2.0: WSO2 Identity server as a key manager in wso2 API Manager

Tags: api, authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity server as a key manager in WSO2 API manager. I am creating sample playground app with OAuth2.0 flow with WSO2 API manager.I have added new app in API store and generated consumer key and consumer secret.

steps:

1. Run Sample playground app -localhost:8080/playground2
   [Playground app home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYDpS.png)
2. Click on Image we will go to `oauth2.jsp` page

here we have to fill:

```
 response_type = code
 client_id = VALUE_OF_CONSUMER_KEY
 redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URL_OF_THE_APPLICATION
 scope = SCOPE_OF_THE_ACCESS_REQUEST
```

[Authorize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjnjY.png)

3. On Clicking Authorize button The application (client) requests an authorization code from the authorization server(WSO2 identity server) by sending a HTTP GET request with the following query parameters.

   ```
    response_type = code

    client_id = VALUE_OF_CONSUMER_KEY

    redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URL_OF_THE_APPLICATION

    scope = SCOPE_OF_THE_ACCESS_REQUEST
   ```

and it displays consent page
[Consent page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udsqx.png)

4. when we click approve it redirects to wso2 login page
   [Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRi9A.png)
5. After entering credentials it gives following error: [AfterLogin Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYDpS.png)

   ```
   HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault

   type Exception report

   message org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault

   description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
   ```

exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
root cause

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:251)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.sendRequestToFramework(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:1163)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:135)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorizePost(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:574)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.73 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.73
```

6. In API Manager console it is giving following error:

I.

```
ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : PBMTE1piS4sKNdn2HdsJAbMeCQga
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - System error occurred. Please check server logs for more details.
            at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
```

II.

```
[2017-03-10 11:48:21,226] ERROR - item-info:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : PBMTE1piS4sKNdn2HdsJAbMeCQga
[2017-03-10 11:48:49,063]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure
[2017-03-10 11:49:02,990]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2017-03-10 11:49:30,889]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-03-10 11:49:31,028]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : jmsEventPublisher initialized
[2017-03-10 11:49:32,336]  INFO - AMQConnection Unable to connect to broker at tcp://localhost:5672
org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:130)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:631)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:628)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:628)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:409)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
```

III.

```
org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:486)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
```

IV.

```
 Caused by: org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
```

V.

```
[2017-03-10 11:49:32,345] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:361)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:40)
```

VI.

```
[2017-03-10 11:49:32,350] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.handleException(JMSConnectionFactory.java:197)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I am confused what you are trying to do?
do you want to test oauth flow with wso2 identity server or want to test IS as a key manager with wso2 API Manager?

Comment: I want to test IS as a key manager with wso2 API Manager.

Comment: In that i don't think you need the playground app at all... Playground app is to test OAuth with Identity Server only. Which versions of IS and APIM are you planning to use?